# Kiel oni diras esperante "to harass"?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

Kiel oni diras esperante “to harass” aŭ “harassment”? En la Telegrama grupo ni konkludis, ke “sexual harassment” povus esti tradukata kiel “seksmolesto” (ĉu ekzistas pli bona traduko?). Tamen, ĉu “molesti” taŭgas por ĉiuj specoj de “harassment”? Ekzemple, kiel oni nomus en Esperanto la konduton de tiu, kiu obsedite telefonas al iu po dek fojoj ĉiutage?

Comment: How about tedi?

Answer (score 7):

*Seksa molestado* is what Benson (CEED) has listed.

Note that, in accordance to PIV, the meaning of "molesti" is much closer to "to harass", and should not be misled by its similarity with the contemporary meaning of "to molest."

Comment: Dankon. Kaj kion ĝi diras pri “harassment” ĝenerale?

Comment: Ankaŭ Tatoeba uzas „seksa molestado”: https://tatoeba.org/epo/sentences/search?query=molestado&from=epo&to=und

Comment: DRR - estis multaj proponoj. Tro por listigi. Mi elektis ne listigi ilin kiam mi rimarkis ke ĝi enahavis apartan mencion de "Seksa molestado".

Comment: Kial ne listigi? Almenaux la plej kutimajn. La demando temas pri cxia "harassment".

Comment: Post tiom da monatoj mi jam ne memoras. Mi supozas ke temas pri manko de tempo, kaj la penso ke ne indas ripeti laboron de vortaro kiu estas facile acxetebla.

Comment: Downvoting because it doesn’t answer the actual question which was about  harassment in a more general sense.

Comment: Suit yoursef, Neil Roberts. What I actually said, though, was that for "harassment in a more general sense", Benson lists *seksa molestado*. In fact, PIV defines "molesti" as - Malamike aŭ insulte trakti, malkomfortigi -- so Benson's definition seems to fit, even if it sounds odd to our English-language ears.

Answer (score 2):

persekuti

*persekut/i: Konstante turmentadi per severaj, maljustaj aŭ kruelaj malbonfaroj aŭ leĝoj (PIV)